# I'm making a HTML5 idle game to practice javascript. Is it possible to save my game in google sheets?

Tags: html, google-apps-script, storage, google-sheets-api

I have recently discovered that is is possible for websites to read JSON data from a Google Sheet using Apps Script. So far, I have not been able to edit data on a Google Sheet from an external javascript file. Is this even possible? If so, how would I go about that? I'm not very advanced so examples would be appriciated.

My idea is to have columns in a google sheet and each person would have an ID saved in their localStorage that would be used for editing specific rows in the Google Sheets and reading the correct data. I have tried finding examples or tutorials on the internet but so far everything has been about pushing form information to a google sheet, not editing existing values.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

To update values in a cell, this function can be used.

```
 function updateValues(spreadsheetId, range, valueInputOption, _values, callback) {
      let values = [
        [
          // Cell values ...
        ],
        // Additional rows ...
      ];
      values = _values;
      const body = {
        values: values,
      };
      try {
        gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.update({
          spreadsheetId: spreadsheetId,
          range: range,
          valueInputOption: valueInputOption,
          resource: body,
        }).then((response) => {
          const result = response.result;
          console.log(`${result.updatedCells} cells updated.`);
          if (callback) callback(response);
        });
      } catch (err) {
        document.getElementById('content').innerText = err.message;
        return;
      }
    }
```

This is taken from their own documentation, where you can also find if you need to update multiple cells.

Documentation can be found here.
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values#javascript

If you want a specific example, you'll have to ellaborate your usecase a bit.